# Program won't terminate despite return statement

Tags: java

Hello I'm new to programming so I'm sorry if the answer is painfully obvious,but I have trouble with my code not terminating after two incorrect inputs despite the return statement being used. The rest of the code works fine when it comes to printing out 3 integers between the range and organizing and categorizing them.

```
System.out.println("Please input a interger between 0-99:");
    int input1 = Input.nextInt();

        if (input1>99||input1<0){ 
            System.out.println("Outside range. Please enter an integer between 0-99");
             input1 = Input.nextInt();
        }        

        else if (input1>99||input1<0){ 
                           System.out.println("Outside range program terminated.");
                          return;                             
        }
    System.out.println("Please input the second interger between 0-99:");
    int input2= Input.nextInt();    
        if (input2>99||input2<0){ 
            System.out.println("Outside range. Please enter an integer between 0-99");
             input2 = Input.nextInt();
        }        

        else if (input2>99||input2<0){ 
                           System.out.println("Outside range program terminated.");
                           System.exit(0);
        }
        if (input1>input2){
            max=input1;
            min=input2; 
        }
        else {
        min=input1;
        max=input2;
        }
  int integer1 = min + (int)(Math.random()* (( max-min)+1));
  int integer2 = min + (int)(Math.random()* (( max-min)+1));
  int integer3 = min + (int)(Math.random()* (( max-min)+1));
        if(integer1>integer2) {
            temp = integer1;
            integer1 = integer2;
            integer2= temp;
        }
            else if (integer2>integer3) {
                temp = integer2;
                integer2=integer3;
                integer3=temp;

        }
        if(integer2>integer3){
            temp=integer2;
            integer2=integer3;
            integer3=temp;


        }
     System.out.println("The range begins at"+min+"and ends at"+max);
     System.out.println("Three sorted random integers between 20 and 80 are:");     
        if (integer1 %2 ==0) {
            System.out.println(+integer1+"\tEven");}
        else {
            System.out.println(+integer1+"\tOdd"); 
                }
       if (integer2 %2 ==0) {
           System.out.println(+integer2+"\tEven");
       }
       else{
           System.out.println(+integer2+"\tOdd");

           if (integer3 %2 ==0){
           System.out.println(+integer3+"\tEven");}
        else{
            System.out.println(+integer3+"\tOdd");
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could fix the insane indentation.

Comment: check  else if you do not whant the else

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is never executed.

```
if (input1>99||input1<0){ 
    System.out.println("Outside range. Please enter an integer between 0-99");
    input1 = Input.nextInt();
}
else if (input1>99||input1<0){ 
    System.out.println("Outside range program terminated.");
    return;                             
}
```

How would you expect to `return` to run? The boolean conditions are the same. If `input1>99||input1<0` then the first `if` statement will execute. If `input1>99||input1<0` is not true, then neither `if` statement will execute. In either situation, the `return` is never reached.